# How to load img with transition in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, transition, react-router-dom

What is correct way to make 'appear' effect for `img` with react?

What we have:

```js
const ProductCard = ({product}) => {

    const [imgLoading, setImgLoading] = useState(true);

    const onLoad = () => {
        setImgLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className={classNames({
            'product-card': true,
            'img-loading': imgLoading,
        })}
        >
            <img
                src={product.photo}
                alt={product.name}
                onLoad={onLoad}
            />
            <div className='img-cover'></div>
            {/* ... */}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I use class `img-loading` to cover the image while it's loading.

```css
.product-card {
  position: relative;
  .img-cover {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1.75s;
  }

  &.img-loading .img-cover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Prop `product` changes when user goes to another page (route).
And first time it works well: when new product comes to props, it renders as expected.
But when user comes back to a page that he has already visited and img loads from cache, it renders without effect I set, it's just shown immediately. I think it's about cache because when I turned on `Disable cache` in chrome dev tools it works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

scroll down to the end of the page and see how it works

"i use this in web design (html,css) not sure about react"

you just add CDN sources and call the class you want